# issue with urbanairship notification plugin of phonegap in android

Tags: android, eclipse, git, cordova, urbanairship.com

I've created a new application with cli with phonegap. everything is going well my app running successfully on emulator and device.

Now i want to use urbanairship push notification. 
i followed the following url

https://github.com/urbanairship/phonegap-ua-push/blob/master/README.md

replaced the css, js and index.html from example to my application.

I use the following command to add the plugin

phonegap local plugin add https://github.com/urbanairship/phonegap-ua-push.git

plugin added successfully 
i changed the key and config.xml

```
<!-- Urban Airship app credentials -->
<preference name="com.urbanairship.production_app_key" value="__SOMETHINGTBmsZLE__SOMETHING" />
<preference name="com.urbanairship.production_app_secret" value="dWFIJuLST__SOMETHING" />
<preference name="com.urbanairship.development_app_key" value="__SOMETHING_3z1gAh__SOMETHING" />
<preference name="com.urbanairship.development_app_secret" value="dWFIJuL__SOMETHING" />

<!-- If the app is in production or not -->
<preference name="com.urbanairship.in_production" value="false" />

<!-- Enable push when the application launches (instead of waiting for enablePush js call).  Defaults to false -->
<preference name="com.urbanairship.enable_push_onlaunch" value="true" />

<!-- Only required for Android. -->
<preference name="com.urbanairship.gcm_sender" value="AIzaSyC5rS_Gv__SOMETHING" />
```

when i run application on emulator with following command

phonegap run android

It is running well but my device is not registering on urbanairship.
 then i open android project in adt (android developement tool ) in eclipse and run from there application running but i got some error in log console.

[image]

i want to know what is wrong with my application.

Answer (score 1):

I honestly do not know why, but you need to have the in_production flag set to true to get push notifications to work on Android.

This was rather annoying when trying to make an application for both iOS and Android as I had to put the dev keys in for the prod. It could also lead to some confusion with deployment. But, doing this will make it work.